# How to write code notes like this style?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to write code notes like the style in the picture in sublime ,how?[image]

Comment: Did you try just typing them, as you would do in any other software?

Comment: You could create a snippet to do this for you. Check out snippets for sublime text [here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html). I would also recommend you check out [DocBlockr](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs#function-documentation) for commenting functions in Javascript, PHP, CoffeeScript, Actionscript, C & C++.